# Keycloak - Chain User Federation Providers together

Tags: security, jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services, wildfly-11

I currently have an LDAP user federation provider and a custom UserStorageProvider spi I wrote to look into my sqlserver DB for user groups. To fully login I need to pass back the user groups to the application, so, they are part of the claims in the KeycloakSecurityContext token string.

Right now either my custom spi validates or the LDAP provider validates depending on the priority number I specify. Is there a way to force keycloak to validate first using the LDAP provider and then also execute the custom provider?

Comment: But is not sufficient to rely on the priorities? I mean the priority for the LDAP should be lower than the one of the custom SPI and ldap will always run first